# How to verify a JWT token signed with x509 with only a public key in AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, x509certificate, pfx, jwt

I have an AspNetCore application which generates a JWT token for me based on a PFX certificate.

```
public string GenerateToken()
{
    using (var certificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx"))
    {
        var credentials = new X509SigningCredentials(certificate);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Tester"),
            }),
            IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = credentials
        };

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = handler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return handler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

And with the same PFX you can verify if the signature is valid.

```
public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
{
    using (var certificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx"))
    {
        var key = new X509SecurityKey(certificate);
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = key
        };

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        try
        {
            var claims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
            if (claims != null && validatedToken != null)
            {
                return claims;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But this requires for other applications which only need to validate the JWT token to also have access to this PFX certificate.

If I take a generated token with this PFX

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZEQzE4QTU4MEI4QjIxNzE4MjY5MTdDNkRGRDdGNjM5NEFBMTAwNDgiLCJ4NXQiOiJiY0dLV0F1TElYR0NhUmZHMzlmMk9VcWhBRWciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Ik5hbWUiLCJyb2xlIjoiVGVzdGVyIiwibmJmIjoxNTY5NDI4MDIwLCJleHAiOjE1Njk1MTQ0MTksImlhdCI6MTU2OTQyODAxOX0.kmszDk3cYEfK7dOzynotOuzTkc0GFIMbRau5ELOUROz5De-6M4YA_tWpjH1Ss6wPM078RKZeMIpolMOGvCLaza1XUp2w7fiJ_zWNJ1r4XiYzfdGiHnrUM7IwjYfwVbV7Ez2sk0FMmka-yO0UeHOKICEoxUAEBA_KzJiWHQfJJssOxcNdu4rwX1CeJ0xnJCKi77GDZ54GhdrQ_NuHzWOQZrsLa7_QfJtNTufOAzAg_kSI7XRCt6LOIkNTiENY_iJSnurlbg0O3VqkmlBvBEOS-ihd0h2Gt_AGEJ22OB4oh7Xip-xf7gm4dPR2u3ISEVmEq5H6J444CDuuKKulB7OLeKEnh9-2fGw8o-q-RIZeOo4r6UqxEW3n6TrEu7hIoAP72x5xc8ptpAPG9GtCsUjMgZcQV4QCLA9zxNxApC6J9cmgZgfI7kTGeardjsy32I23BjUl0AH0c4lh5I3SVeZB7W0mvqLj_UG_O8o57c-0dhU5kcYXJjI5gtQc1gba0ZCokA5NomnHmtpWuNvtRp4O2PwbyjM2O2RxxN07fAkPC1o4Ukm-b_n_OudyznLfmFZwv9wxqn5n-_vIy4WPuM1tm-LIzuXb0dRHDJrI8OPtj43VKNMEkQO604Fb13tVvj3iMB_n3ZWSMuLtMBLNeIED-3eynZfnr0vdMYktHNsvf6o
```

and place it in https://jwt.io/ I only need the public key to validate the signature.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I would like that other application *only* require my public key so i do not have to distribute the PFX over multiple applications (which allows them to generate JWT tokens by themself).

How can I validate JWT tokens signed with a X509 certificate with only the public key in AspNetCore?

Comment: you can distribute only public part of certificate to validate the token. No need to distribute PFX to validate the token.

Comment: I *think* you can create instances of `X509SecurityKey` that only contain a public key. Export the certificate without the private key, load up that there and see what happens? :)

Comment: @juunas. The only way a `X509SecurityKey` is constructed is with a `X509Certificate2`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.x509securitykey?view=azure-dotnet.
Isn't there another way?

Comment: @Crypt32. Do you have an example for this? It would really help.

Comment: Use `RawData` property on X509Certificate2 object and save byte array to a.CER file. Then in 2nd code snippet replace.PFX file with. CER file.

Answer (score 2):

Base on the suggestion of @Crypt32 i was able to generate a seperate certificate.

```
using (var certificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx"))
{
    using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        await file.WriteAsync(certificate.RawData);
    }
}
```

With this new certificate I was able to validate tokens successfully, but when trying the create a new token I received an `InvalidOperationException`.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=IDX10638: Cannot create the SignatureProvider, 'key.HasPrivateKey' is false, cannot create signatures. Key: [PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.].
  Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityTokenPrivate(String issuer, String audience, ClaimsIdentity subject, Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, Nullable`1 issuedAt, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor)
```

So this seems to be the way of distributing a JWT token validator.

Comment: Rather than create yet another file (can you even be sure you have write permission?), simply create a new X509Certificate2 passing in the RawData of the full certifcate:
var publiconlyCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.RawData);

Comment: @9Rune5 -- that comment deserves to be its own answer. :) Thank you so much!!